# does match () against () needs 4 parameters to work?

Tags: mysql, search-engine, match

hello im trying to make a search engine and im using match() against() to match my keywords to the keyword of the user.. when i assigned my parameters to be 4 it doesn't show any error but when i have it on 3 or 2 i keep on having this error:

**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...**

this is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$keyword = "'".$_POST["keywords"]."'";


$result = " SELECT *, MATCH(title,body,meta_keywords) AGAINST
($keyword) AS score FROM articles WHERE MATCH(title,body,meta_keywords) AGAINST($keyword) GROUP BY url";

$query = mysql_query($result);

}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['title'] . "<br/ >";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT *, count (MATCH(title,body,meta_keywords) AGAINST
($keyword)) AS score FROM articles WHERE MATCH(title,body,meta_keywords) AGAINST($keyword IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score GROUP BY url

maybe it there are some errors in sintaxs i didnt run it

you can find more at [mysql full text search in boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: i tried the code but it still has the same error.. here: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: what is the value of keywords ? do you have the table setup corectly ?
what this say 
$query = mysql_query($result);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n"
the $link is frome something like 
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

Comment: $keywords < this is where the search term of the user will be stored.. yes i have setup the table correctly.. i dont think the problem is on my connection because if i have my 4 parameters in match() against() everything is working fine.. my problem is that every time i set it less than 4 it gives me that error..